# React Native Version Mismatch - APK works, aab not

Tags: javascript, apk, react-native

Link to picture (not yet any reputation): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf1M8.jpg

I'm getting React Native Version Mismatch after upgrading React Native from 0.58.X to 0.59.9.

My biggest concern is that if I build a **signed APK** by Android Studio, installs the APK on device (S8, API level 27), it **works**. But when generating (via Android Studio) and uploading the **aab-file** to Play Store, download and installs it, I get the version mismatch problem.

I've googled around like a small angry man, tried the following (and a lot more..):

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24529#issuecomment-536774479
- dependencies{
  compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.9") { force = true } 
  }
- Full reset (clean, reset cache, rm node-modules etc)
- android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: Did you choose release when signing the abb because it seems what you upload to play store is the debug version

Comment: Yes @harisu I did choose release. But you have a great point there, it seems that it's the debug version that is uploaded..

Comment: I might try ./gradlew bundleRelease @harisu and upload the generated .aab. I dislike though that it's not testable..

Comment: Its testable. Its just require a little more work. You can after getting the abb use the bundle tool to split the apk thesame tool google uses to distribute your app https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool

Answer (score 0):

Solution: ./gradlew bundleRelease, as Android Studio seemed to sign debugversion, even though release was choosen.. will have to investigate that a bit more!